# EF / SQL Statement Takes Way Too Long for Small Dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some code written in C# / WebApi that utilizes entity framework to return data to a DataTables (JS plugin) table. We are using DataTables to allow for searching, sorting, and paging of the data to improve response times.

However, sorting by certain columns (and not others) causes a timeout. In looking at the SQL generated by EF, the SQL that times out looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[Entity_Number] AS [Entity_Number], 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[name_first] AS [name_first], 
    [Project1].[name_last] AS [name_last], 
    [Project1].[Filed_Dt] AS [Filed_Dt], 
    [Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Project1].[Display_Name] AS [Display_Name], 
    [Project1].[Modified_By] AS [Modified_By], 
    [Project1].[Locked_By_Admin_User] AS [Locked_By_Admin_User], 
    [Project1].[Review_Comment] AS [Review_Comment], 
    [Project1].[Display_Name1] AS [Display_Name1], 
    [Project1].[Correspond_Dt] AS [Correspond_Dt]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[Entity_Number] AS [Entity_Number], 
        [Extent1].[Filed_Dt] AS [Filed_Dt], 
        [Extent1].[Correspond_Dt] AS [Correspond_Dt], 
        [Extent1].[Review_Comment] AS [Review_Comment], 
        [Extent1].[Locked_By_Admin_User] AS [Locked_By_Admin_User], 
        [Extent1].[Modified_By] AS [Modified_By], 
        [Extent5].[name_first] AS [name_first], 
        [Extent5].[name_last] AS [name_last], 
        [Extent6].[Name] AS [Name], 
        [Extent7].[Display_Name] AS [Display_Name], 
        [Extent8].[Display_Name] AS [Display_Name1], 
        CASE WHEN (DATEPART (year, [Extent3].[Cycle_End]) IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE  CAST( DATEPART (year, [Extent3].[Cycle_End]) AS nvarchar(max)) END AS [C1]
        FROM        [dbo].[MCLE_Affidavit] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[MCLE_Affidavit_Status] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Aff_Status_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[MCLE_Ed_Year] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[MCLE_EdYear_Id] = [Extent3].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Named_Entity] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent1].[Entity_Number] = [Extent5].[entity_number]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[MCLE_Affidavit_Type] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent1].[Aff_Type_Id] = [Extent6].[Id]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[MCLE_Affidavit_Status] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent1].[Aff_Status_Id] = [Extent7].[Id]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[MCLE_Filer_Type] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent1].[Filer_Type_Id] = [Extent8].[Id]
        WHERE ( NOT (([Extent2].[Group] IN ('Compliant', 'NA', 'Void', 'Administrative')) AND ([Extent2].[Group] IS NOT NULL))) AND ([Extent1].[Filer_Type_Id] IS NOT NULL)
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[name_last] ASC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

However, a nearly identical query, where the only change is "ORDER BY [Project1].[Entity_Number]" returns results in <1 second. Going through the list of columns returned, the time is <1 second for Entity_Number, Id, C1, Name, Display_Name, Modified_By, Locked_By_Admin_User, Review_Comment, Display_Name1, and Correspond_Dt but never seems to finish when using Name_Last, Name_First, or Filed_Dt - at least not within 15 minutes.

Also, if the query is run without the OFFSET/FETCH the results return in <1 second regardless of the column used in the ORDER BY.

For reference, there are only 5 records in my test environment that are "NOT IN ('Compliant', 'NA', 'Void', 'Administrative')". The SQL server is MSSQL Server 2016 SP1.

I have tried adding an index (Non Clustered) to name_last, but it made no noticeable difference.

Can someone provide an explanation on why certain columns cause a timeout, or direction on how to diagnose the problem?

UPDATE:
The estimated execution plan is :
[image: Execution Plan]
I can't get the actual one since the query never seems to finish. I've let it sit for 90 minutes and it's still going. I'm not entirely sure how to read this but I don't see anything that stands out as an explanation for why the query takes so long.

@akseli - Split Queries are available in .Net Core. I'm not using Core.

@Stu - The ORM may indeed create poor queries, but I believe the SQL is reasonably well written in this case since it executes as expected for certain fields. The problem here is not the ORM, per se, but that it doesn't execute well for the other fields, whether the execution is in C# code or in an SSMS query window.

Comment: Please try to read how to get execution plan for the query. And, of course, read this article https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: You might want to look into `Split Queries` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries this may help out with your performance issues.

Comment: ORMs are fine for simple crud-type stuff but for more complex queries if you want good performance, imho craft well-written sql.

Comment: It is just a guess but, when you use `[Project1].[Entity_Number]`,the server might be using 'nested loops' to get one row from that table, and find the matching entries and return, and continue until 10 rows are returned; but when you use the other columns, it may be choosing to execute the complete query, sort the results and then start sending rows. Which method it uses/when depends on which columns are indexed, and the distribution of values in them (statistics); you can see better if you look at the execution plans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit belongs to @Sergey and @tinazmu who got me pointed in the right direction. I had to wait for the query to finish - which took nearly 2 hours. The actual execution plan included a suggested index which brought the search time down to 4.5 minutes. A second suggested index dropped the search time to less than a second.

From my reading here https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/learn/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/ it seems that the two recommended indexes were "covering indexes". If I read this right, it is probable that "the query optimizer determined that the overhead cost of performing a Key Lookup for each of the rows was more than simply traversing the entire table via a table scan" which made at least one of the existing indexes useless for this query.